# Distributing $19$ different presents to $6$ children so that each has at least $2$ presents?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you distribute $19$ different presents among $6$ children so each can get at least $2$ presents?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. It would help if you could show us what you have tried.

Comment: Using the formula $ binom (n+k-1 ,k) $ I replace $k$ with$ k-2n$ and then multiply by 19! and plug in $n=6$ and $k=19$.But it seems incorrect

Comment: Not only is the title unninformative, but it is definitely not on the harder side of the spectrum.

Comment: No, I was just about to answer :'(

Comment: What you want is the 2-associated stirling number of the second kind $S_2(17,6)$ multiplied by $6!$

Comment: @ModdedBear: It actually is on the harder end of the spectrum for students who are very likely to encounter it, i.e., those taking a typical sophomore-level discrete math course. Such students are unlikely to know anything about Stirling numbers, let alone $r$-associated Stirling numbers.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right about that. I was misguided by the title (usually questions with hard on the title are easy) and the fact presents and children where involved.

Comment: @Kevin: Your calculation would work if the presents were indistinguishable; the fact that they are different makes the question a lot harder.

Comment: Since the question is closed, I'll write this comment. Use polynomial coefficient: you have $\binom{19}{2}$ options for the first kid, $\binom{17}{2}$ for the second etc, so you get $\frac{19!}{7!2^6}$. The remaining 7 presents can be distributed in any way, clearly there are $6^7$ ways for this. Hence the solution is $\frac{19!}{7!2^6}6^7 $

Comment: Alex, you are overcounting. and the worst part is the number of times a solution is being overcounted is not equal for each solution. The reason you are overcounting is that giving presents $1$ and $2$ to bob and then having bob get present $3$ after should be the same as giving presents $2$ and $3$ to Bob and then having Bob get present $1$ after.

Comment: Can someone post the right answer now the question is reopened to the benefit of all.

Comment: I'm not sure, the link to the OEIS sequence gives their generating function but I haven't checked it out yet.

Comment: @ModdedBear: OK yeah I see now. The problem would have much easier if each kid was to get at least 3 presents (4+3+3+3+3+3 in $\binom{6}{1}$ ways)

Answer (score 1):

You need the $2-$ associated Stirling numbers of the second kind. The idea is that to give out the presents you can first separate the presents into six groups of size at least two and then chose which group you want to give to each children (Clearly once the presents have been seperated into groups there are $6!$ ways to do this.

But how many ways are there to seperate the $17$ presents into $6$ groups of size at least $2$? This number is precisely the $2-$ associated Stirling number of the second kind $S_2(17,6)$. The $2-$ associated Stirling numbers of the second kind can be found in this OEIS sequence http://oeis.org/A008299.

You can download the text file with a lot of values [here](http://oeis.org/A008299/b008299.txt) although finding the exact term may be slightly tricky. you should be able to find $S_2(19,6)$ which is $254752658160$. So what you want is $6!\times 254752658160= 183421913875200$

Also note that you can calculate the values of $S_2(n,k)$ yourself  by using the recurrence $S_2(n+1,k)=S_2(n,k)+nS_2(n,k-1)$

The explanation for the recurrence is simple. Pick a fixed present $a$. There aare two types of distributions possible, those in which the group of $a$ still has at least two presents after removing $a$ (there are $S_2(n,k)$ of these since removing $a$ gives a valid partition of $n$ presents in $k$ groups of at least two presents each). The other type of partition is that in which removing present $a$ leaves a present alone. There are $n(S_2(n,k-1)$ partitions of this type since removing present $a$ and the present that is left alone gives us a valid partition of $n$ presents in $k-1$ groups of at least two presents each, and there are $n$ possibilities for the present that could have been with $a$.

Finally I would like to say  there is a similar recurrence for $S_r(n,k)$ and that the numbers $S_2(n,k)$ are also called the Ward numbers and they are the coefficients of the [Mahler Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_polynomial).

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new today.

Comment: typo 19 not 17. excellent answer though. +1

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks

Comment: In looking at the stirling numbers of the second kind wiki, won't the formula give me all subsets, even those that are not of size at least 2? How do I specify to count only subsets of at least size 2?

Comment: those are just the stirling coefficients of the second kind. You want the 2-associated stirling coefficients of the second kind. I have to leave, I'll come back in seven hours though :)

Comment: Also, it doesn't give you the subsets, it gives you the partitions.