# How do I count number of ways of drawing items with certain number of duplicates?

Tags: combinatorics

How do I count the number of ways of drawing `K` items (with replacement) from a pool of `N` items such that I have at least `D` copies of each of any `E` different items.

For example if there are 10 distinct coupons, how many ways can I draw 100 random coupons and have at least 3 copies of any 5 of them.

I initially thought of inclusion-exclusion and start with `n^k` and then discount the number of ways of not having the required duplicates, but couldn't get a formula.

Another example: If there are 3 different coupons and I want to draw 5 at random such that there are 2 copies of at least 2 of them

Drawing:
11223 is a success
11123 is a failure
11122 is a success

Comment: Order of extraction matters? 11223 and 22311 count as two extractions or one?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to count the number of functions from the set $\{1,2,3\dots K\}$ to the set $\{1,2,3\dots N\}$ so that the pre-image of every element of $\{1,2,3\dots K\}$ has size at least $D$.

We can solve this problem using the $D$-associated stirling numbers of the second kind.

The $D$-Associated number of the second kind $S_D(N,K)$ gives you the number of partitions the set $\{1,2\dots N\}$ has into $K$ parts of size at least $D$.

Look at the problem this way. What you want to count is the number of ways to color the integers from $1$ to $N$ with $K$ colors so that there are at least $D$ integers of each color. To do this you can first divide the integers into $K$ classes and then select which color gets each of the $k$ classes in $k!$ ways.

The number of ways to divide the integers into classes is $S_D(N,K)$.

Hence what you want is $S_D(n,k)\times k!$.

---

Note that in general it is hard to calculate the $D$-associated striling numbers , although they do follow the recurrence $S_D(N+1,K)=KS_D(N,K)+\binom{N}{D-1}S_D(N-D+1,K-1)$

[I wrote a similar answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1104223/33907)

Comment: It depends what he meant by "any `E`". You assumed it meant that "for all combinations of `E` types of objects, there are at least `D` objects of any of the `E` types". Notice how this is the same as saying "there are at least `D` objects of any type", which means it seems unlikely that OP meant the problem to be like this, considering the complicated phrasing and unnecessarily adding a constant `E`. Notice how you never actually mentioned `E` in your answer. I'd say OP probably meant "there exist `E` different types of objects such that there are at least `D` objects of each of the E types".

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I seem to have answered the case when $E=D$.

Comment: @user314 I'll edit my post with an example.

Comment: @ModdedBear Your answer incorrectly assumes that every type of object has to be drawn. You seem to misunderstand what is wrong with your answer. Your answer assumes that every type (of the K types) of object must be drawn at least D times, but OP meant that that there exist at least E types, not necessarily all of the types, that at least D of each of those E types is drawn. E.g., consider OP's example, which says 11122 is a success even though there are 3 types of objects and the 3rd type is not drawn.

Comment: Yeah, I answered the case when $E=K$. I think I can get a summation over $D$ associated stirlings to fix this.

Comment: @user314 thanks for the recommendation. I will.

Comment: @ModdedBear Your other comment said $E=D$ while you meant $E=K$, which is why I wrote the second comment.

Comment: I was responding to the comment you deleted that said  "great, you should try it then"